# OpenGL prevent stretching on window resize

Tags: vb.net, opengl, opentk

I have a ortho set up at the moment for 2D, when I resize the window it stretches anything that is drawn in the window, is there a way to either just have black bars show when the window is resized or at least maintain the aspect ratio of the contents, so they dont stretch at all. I have tried a few implementations that I have seen on here, but nothing really works.

EDIT: Sorry guys had a bit of a blonde moment

```
    Protected Overrides Sub OnResize(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnResize(e)

        GL.Viewport(0, 0, Width, Height)

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection)
        GL.LoadIdentity()
        GL.Ortho(-1.0, testvalue, testvalue , 1.0, 0.0, 4.0)
    End Sub
```

testvalue at the moment is 5000, window size is 800x800

Comment: Please include the actual code you are using the setup your "ortho"graphic projection matrix when the window changes dimensions. For this to work the way you want, I would expect to see some math to compensate for the aspect ratio before and after the window is resized.

Comment: Edited! I did try and incorporate an aspect ratio, by multiplying test value by width/height but it was very dodgy and didn't really maintain the ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I had to do. Rather than utilizing the aspect ratio on the Ortho part, I used it on the view port as such:

```
Dim ar As Single = Width/Height
GL.Viewport( 0, 0, 800 * ar, 800 * ar)
```

This prevents all stretching and simply places a black bar on the right hand side when the width is greater than height.

Answer (score 0):

the ortho command comprises of: the following parameters: left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar further info: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml

You will want to plug in your 'Width' into right and your 'Height' into bottom and ensure the Width and Height values reflect the new window size.

E.g.:

```
GL.Viewport(0, 0, Width, Height)
GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection)
GL.LoadIdentity()
GL.Ortho(0.0, Width, Height, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0)
```

Since you're only after 2D your zNear and zFar can be quite small, just make sure to render between zNear and zFar and do not use 0.0 as your zNear, I would recommend using 0.1 or larger for your zNear.

Answer (score 0):

When you resize, Windows creates its own message pump to handle events, bypassing your message pump. There are work-arounds (hacks) to get it to render whilst sizing, including running your update/rendering on a thread.  Note that this is a problem for D3D as well as OpenGL.

There's a discussion [here on an old Gamedev thread](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/488074-win32-message-pump-and-opengl---rendering-pauses-while-draggingresizing/).